# Drawerlayout with disabled drawerindicator shows only not working arrow

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using the navdrawer layout from android to show a filter on the right side of my screen in a sliding menu.

Now I wanted to remove the left icon in the toolbar. I did this as follows:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

The only problem I'm now facing is that the icon is an arrow and it doesn't do anything and I want it still to have the up behaviour.

I tried something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_filter:
            Timber.d("Open or close filter");
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.openDrawer();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But this doens't work because onOptionsItemSelected is not called for that arrow?

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: After doing the setup method of the navdrawer you need to do these lines. Thanks.